# Why is this always giving me the current time

Tags: scripting, vbscript

```
    If internal_isTurnedOn And Right(LCase(internal_CurrentUser), 8) = "lastname"  Then     
        Dim value: value = CDate(InputBox("enter the date and time (hh:mm)", "please", FormatDateTime(Time, 4)))     
        ' validate the input here     
        internal_Time = CDate(value)  
    Else
        internal_Time = CDate(Time)
    End If
```

I get the input box and no matter what value I enter, it gives me the current time.
I want the default to remain the current time (displayed) but if the user changes it to another value then I want the changed value

UPDATE TO CODE

```
    If internal_isTurnedOn And Right(LCase(internal_CurrentUser), 8) = "lastname"  Then
        Dim value
        value = CDate(InputBox("Please enter the time (hh:mm)", "Time Input", FormatDateTime(Now, 4)))             
        internal_Time = CDate(FormatDateTime(value, 4))
    Else
        internal_Time = FormatDateTime(Time, 4)
    End If
```

However now I am getting the correct time that I've inputted but it is adding some extra unwanted things like seconds and AM/PM. Anyway to just get the time in military format?

Comment: To get just military time, change the 4th line to: internal_Time = FormatDatetime(CDate(value), 4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm, I tried your code and as long as I got the prompt, I could set the time.  Are you sure it's not getting reset somewhere later in your code?

Just to be sure, can you put something like this right after the End if:

```
msgbox(internal_Time)
```

To return the time as just military time, without AM/PM, use this:

```
internal_Time = FormatDatetime(CDate(value), 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

probably your condition 
If internal_isTurnedOn And Right(LCase(internal_CurrentUser), 8) = "lastname"  would be returning false always
chk your condition

Comment: I debugged it and I am getting the InputBox. It was a good guess but there has to be something else. I'm betting it has something to do with FormatDateTime(Time, 4)

Comment: then probably check your other part of code which is resetting the internal_time variable